# Active directory signout not working in Azure environment

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD authentication for one of our project which is azure web service and it is working fine in localhost but when I deploy it in azure environment logout is not working properly. When I try to signing out it's taking me to Microsoft sign out page but suddenly it is redirecting to my home page without any authentication.
Below is a sample link triggering when I try to sign out.

**https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-key/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyprojectwebapp.azurewebsites.net%2FAccount%2FSignOutCallback&x-client-SKU=ID_NET451&x-client-ver=5.2.2.0**

For localhost it's working fine. Please let me know if anyone have solution for this problem. Thanks in advance!!

Regards,
Ali

Answer (score 0):

when you try to signing out from the application, it uses the postLogoutRedirectUri which is defined in the web.config(PostLogoutRedirectURI is the unique identifier to which Azure AD will redirect the user in OAuth request). this maybe the reason why you are redirecting to the home page

Comment: Thanks @Yuvaranjani for your response but it's not the reason. I provided proper PostLogoutRedirectURI. The problem is it stopped working as it is working before.